# Additionally, a 404 Not Found

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, error-handling

A try to make my own errordocument on Localhost...

In my .htaccess:

**ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php**

In the errros directory: 404.php

The .htaccess in the root directory.

But if i tpye some invalid url, like: http://localhost/test/index.pXX, then i got an error:

Not Found

The requested URL /webtest/index.pXX was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

In the 404.php the first line:

What is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you point your browser directly at the http://your.site/errors/404.php url?

I suspect your paths may be a bit confused.

C.

Comment: If i point directly, then show the 404.php. So its not the problem..Any other suggest?

Comment: Strange - try using the full URL for the handler?

Comment: yesss. it's ok. If use the full URL then OK! Thank u!